# CSS image doesn't load for 404 page

Tags: css, image

The page at [example.co.in](http://example.co.in) has a custom 404 page located at [example.co.in/errors/404.html](http://example.co.in/errors/404.html).

When I try accessing a non existent page from within the **errors** directory like this [example.co.in/errors/baba](http://example.co.in/errors/baba) (this page doesnt exist) I get the proper 404 page. However when I try to access a nonexistent page from a directory  above or from any other directory I get the page ***but the image doesnt load***.

The image is located in the **errors** directory same as the **404.html** page.

```
<img src="rajni.jpg">
```

If I put the image in the main html directory (www) it works perfectly fine. The question is why does [example.co.in/errors/baba](http://example.co.in/errors/baba) work and  [example.co.in/baba](http://example.co.in/baba)  not work?

**EDIT:** The links have been changed and wont work because of an SEO problem.

Comment: post your `.htaccess`

Comment: im using virtual host configuration in apache no htaccess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a relative path to the `<img>` `src`.  The actual image is at `/errors/rajni.jpg`.  Thus the image will only load if the path is in `/errors`.  To fix this, simply change the `src`:

```
<img src="/errors/rajni.jpg">
```

How apache serves it is different than how the browser requests it. The browser must make a separate HTTP request for every resource it downloads including the image. It makes one request to `/not/a/page`. Apache sees `/not/a/page and returns`HTTP: 404; html=`(basically). The browser parses HTML, displays, and sees`src=rajni.jpg`. Then it makes another request:`GET HTTP 1.1 /not/a/page/rajni.jpg`. Apache is happy to respond with another 404

Comment: I get that but why does it not work because the image is already in the same folder as the document ... why this weird path issue ? because its working from within the **errors** directory .. so whats causing it ?

Comment: The browser is the one that's making the decision it's not aware that there is an error folder unless you tell it that specifically.

Comment: @woofmeow With its current path (nothing) it will try to load from the *same* directory.  So if you are already in `errors` it tries to load from `/errors/`

Comment: But when i enter a nonexistent page other than from **/errors/** isn't apache supposed to serve the **/errors/404.html** page from the **/errors/** directory ? Or am i understanding something wrong @ExplosionPills ,rosscowar

Comment: @rosscowar isnt apache supposed to correctly serve the request from the **/errors/** folder ?

Comment: @woofmeow How apache serves it is different than how the browser requests it.  The browser must make a separate HTTP request for *every* resource it downloads including the image.  It makes one request to `/not/a/page`.  Apache sees `/not/a/page` and returns `HTTP: 404; html=<img src=rajni.jpg>` (basically).  The browser parses HTML, displays, and sees `src=rajni.jpg`.  Then it makes another request: `GET HTTP 1.1 /not/a/page/rajni.jpg`.  Apache is happy to respond with another 404

Comment: Ah now i get it was kinda silly of me... thanks @ExplosionPills ... could you add this last bit of info to the answer so i could accept it   (upvoted already)

Comment: Hi @ExplosionPills is there anyway i can delete this question ... its showing up in search results for the particular website .... its not acceptable to the site owner ... i just dont want you to lose the points .. is there a way for me to delete it and not affect your points ?

Comment: @woofmeow edit the question to remove the reference to the site

Comment: Cool thanks @ExplosionPills ill let it remain on example.co.in since i dont have another server right now with access to directories that wont cause a migration problem later

Answer (score -1):

Use following line:-

`<img src="http://example.co.in/errors/rajni.jpg">`

Comment: Please do explain your answer too.